# Silverlight and XmlnsDefinition

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Consider 3 assemblies:

- EntryPoint (SL app)
- ClassLibraryA
- ClassLibraryB

Where there is a class `A` in ClassLibraryAand a class `B` in ClassLibraryB

EntryPoint has a reference to ClassLibraryA, and ClassLibraryAhas a reference to ClassLibraryB.

In the `AssemblyInfo` of ClassLibrary1 I have the following code:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "test")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "ClassLibraryA")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "ClassLibraryB", AssemblyName = "ClassLibraryB")]
```

`A` and `B` are both `FrameworkElement`s

The problem is that in my `MainPage`, when I have this xaml:

```
xmlns:test="http://schemas.test.com/sl/"
```

the following doesn't work:

```
<test:B x:Name="bar" />
```

while this works:

```
<test:A x:Name="foo" />
```

Why not?

Comment: Is ClassLibrary1 == ClassLibraryA? You mention 3 assemblies then start talking about ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 which are not listed in those 3 assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Snake

In ClassLibraryA's AssemblyInfo.cs you need to have the following

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "test")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "ClassLibraryA")]
```

and in ClassLibraryB's AssemblyInfo.cs you need to have the following,

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "test")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/sl/", "ClassLibraryB")]
```

Comment: Ok thanks :D but then what is the AssemblyName on the XmlnsDefinition for? :)

Comment: I haven't used the AssemblyName before. so no clue. But, seeing this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.serialization.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx. `It is the name of the current assembly. It defines a mapping between a common language runtime namespace that is defined in the current assembly and an XML namespace`